# Calling superclass method from a subclass instance

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

So I have the following code :

```
class Super {
    private String name="super";
    public String name(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
class Sub extends Super {
    private String name = "sub";
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Sub().name());
    }
}
```

what I get is as result is : super . 
I wasnt to know why ?! Isn't the method `name()` supposed to call `this` of the object that was called from and since `Sub` extends `Super` then it should be able to use it on its members ?!

Comment: One simple rule to remember: **fields are not polymorphic**, only methods are (unless they are private, final or static).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking that the `name` member field in `Sub` should be *overriding* the `name` member field in `Super`. It does not: fields cannot be overridden in Java. Moreover, you've defined both fields as `private`, meaning that member is only visible to other members of that class (and *not* members of derived classes or of other classes). So in your code, `Super` has its own private definition of the `name` field, and `Sub` has its own completely different private definition. Neither is aware of the existence of the other.

Standard practice in Java is to use *getters and setters* to access internal data. If need be, you are then free to override it in derived classes.

Comment: There is no `virtual` keyword in Java.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Sorry, brain fart. I use Java, C++, C# and a few other languages on a daily basis and it's sometimes hard to keep them straight! ;)

Comment: I expected that was the issue! :)